# Optimization question help??

Tags: calculus, optimization

[image]

Here is my problem. I have already completed question 1 and found the areas of constraint and my objective function. My problem is, I don't know how to find h and I don't know how to solve question 2. Here is how I got my objective function:

So basically I knew that the volume is a maximum and I had to find the function that I wanted to maximize. Our volume formula is v = l*w*h and our length is x-2h our width is y-2h and our height is h (which I don't know)

so my equation looked like this: v = h(x-2h)(y-2h)

I foiled first and got h(xy-2xh-2yh+4h^2)

then I distributed in my h and got v = hxy- 2xh^2 - 2yh^2 + 4h^3

And that is my answer for my objective function or the function we wish to maximize. In the photo I sent, I created the table that I need for question 2 but I don't know what we need to create a table for or how to use it. I also don't know how to find h please help!

If you can't see the photo, question 2 asks "Make a table with 3 columns: x, y, Objective function. (see examples from class). Experiment with different values of x and y to see if you can guess what the maximum volume should be. Clearly identify your guess about the maximum volume."

Comment: Please do not post pictures with extensive text as it is not searchable.  Show your commitment and take the time to write it out.  You'll get more help that way too.

Comment: I did write it out. At the very bottom, I have posted what question 2 says. I figured the visual would help for the box itself.

Answer (score 1):

In this question there are three optimization variables $h, x, y$. Also, you have forgot about the constraint $xy=80$. You can reduce the problem to two variables with help of this constraint.

For intuition, even when you fix $x$ and $y$. You can change the volume by varying $h$. Basically, you can make a tall rectangular box with very small base area or a box with large base area but small in height.